# How to recognize Surface Pro Pen in flutter dektop application

Tags: flutter, paint, surface-pro

I want to build a desktop app with flutter. It should look like the program MS-paint but for my Surface pro 7 and it should be able to determine if I am currently using my Microsoft-Pen or my hand. Because when I use my hand, of course I dont want my program to draw anything.
Also I want to know when the user uses the rubber of the pen (the other side). And the one button on the pen.

Any ideas how to get this information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Pen & Windows Ink settings I unchecked the check for Let me use my pen as a mouse in some desktop apps and my pen started working on my Flutter app.